# how to fetch data from webpage in java or python

Tags: java, python, search

I Am Working on project  and in a specific part i need to search for some information and get the results of this search from the internet so how the data can be fetched from the web page to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Selenium - Here's a nice tutorial https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

Selenium is a java library, that supports all major browsers. The download and documentation links can be found on its website - https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with python library *beautifulsoup*.